# Como Embaralhar Valor Da String? (JAVA ANDROID)

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

É o seguinte, estou criando um aplicativo android e presciso embaralhar o valor de uma string.

Exemplo:

String name = "Bruno";

Embaralha o valor da string(name).

Saída: "ronub"

Comment: Olá Bruno tudo bem, procure formular as suas perguntas de uma forma que fique claro a sua dúvida. O que você já fez ou tentou. Exponha o código onde você tem a dúvida, assim fica mais fácil ajudar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Esta função vai solucionar:

```
    public static String shuffle(String text) {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Character> collect = text.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Character> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (collect.size() > 0) {
            Character character = collect.remove(random.nextInt(collect.size()));
            newList.add(character);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character c : newList) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

rodei por exemplo 10 vezes com meu nome "Thiago Born" e os resultados foram:

```
oTaon hgBri
onogBirTh a
r iaghoTBno
ronBTgiao h
BigTo hanro
Ta noBhorgi
oBnTg ahori
onhTgBir oa
hBro aigTno
ahrB Toigno
```

Comment: qual seria o motivo do downvote? a resposta é exatamente o que o usuário quer